# USB Not Select-able from Boot Menu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, usb, usb-boot

I installed Ubuntu on a USB drive following these instructions: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-the-easy-way/

When I go to boot menu the USB drive does not show up. I also downloaded Make Bootable Device from: http://www.megaleecher.net/Make_Bootable_USB and my USB drive is not select-able from this program either.

I am running Windows 7 on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: Have you ever boot your system form the USB?

Comment: Have you configured BIOS to try booting from USB before booting from HD?

Answer (score 3):

It this device bootable from other machines? If not, it is the drive. If it does boot, it means your motherboard does not support booting from USB.